# On the Python Tkinter Canvas widget, how do you lock the y coordinate of the mouse?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to 'lock' the mouse into a specific Y coordinate on the Tkinter Canvas, so that when a user moves the mouse they can traverse the X axis but not the Y (the mouse would slide left and right but never up/down). Is there was a way to do this and how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to do something like that in a game library, but to the best of my knowledge, this is not supported in a GUI library. You should try [PyGame](http://pygame.org/news.html) or [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home).

Comment: Alright, thank you. My backup plan is to just use a canvas item like polygon, hide the cursor, update the polygon along the mouse x axis, and keep a constant y axis.